# 3d Image reconstruction

Tags: image-processing, image3d

I'm using Image3D to reconstruct a 3d image from over 800 2d slices. I'm able to create the image but takes too long to do anything useful with the 3d image. Even rotating the output freezes mathematica. Is there another faster way to  reconstruct and manipulate a 3d image?

Comment: According to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/WolframResearch/status/789581182455451649) the situation is going to improve a lot in *Mathematica* 11.1. Until then, no silver bullet that I know of. If you can sacrifice quality you could skip some layers, and stretch the ones you keep to make up for it.

Comment: One option might be just don't use the front end for viewing, simply process and export without generrating any output cells.